# Объединение словарей лежащих внутри списка

Tags: python

Можно ли как то объединить внутри списка словари? Пробовал через collections,
получалось объединить, но не вложенные конструкции.

Пример

```
list_ = [
    {
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'obj_1',
        'some_fields': [
            {
                'name': "1",
                'values': [
                    {
                        'value': 1
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                'name': "2",
                'values': [
                    {
                        'value': 2
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'obj_2',
        'some_fields': [
            {
                'name': "3",
                'values': [
                    {
                        'value': 3
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                'name': "4",
                'values': [
                    {
                        'value': 4
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]

result = [
    {
        'id': [1, 2],
        'name': ['obj_1', 'obj_2'],
        'some_fields': [
            {
                'name': ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
                'values': [
                    {
                        'value': [1, 2, 3, 4]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Что хоть попробовали покажите.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50441027/recursively-merge-dicts-so-that-elements-with-shared-key-are-combined-into-a-lis